# AJAX Call not showing original page or refreshing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, refresh

OK, so I'm trying to pass an AJAX call in Wordpress via a plugin which is working fine, but this Javascript below won't go back to the original page after the data is passed to the function further below.  What am I missing?

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// We'll pass this variable to the PHP function outofoffice_ajax_request
id_numbers = new Array();
// This does the ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: "get",        
    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
    dataType : "json",
    data: {         
        action:"outofoffice_ajax_request",
        outofoffice_value : outofoffice_value,
        aid : aid
    },
    success:function(response){
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        id_numbers = response;
        $("#outofoffice").html(response);   
                    window.location.reload(true);
    }       
    .error(function() {
alert("Your out of office settings could not be updated.");
})      
})
});
```

Returns the "value is set!" from this function;

```
function outofoffice_ajax_request() {
// The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
if ( isset($_REQUEST['outofoffice_value']) ) {
    $outofoffice = $_REQUEST['outofoffice_value'];
    $aid = $_REQUEST['aid'];
    if($_REQUEST['outofoffice_value']=='true'){
    update_user_meta($aid, 'si_office_status', 'false');  
    }
    else{
    update_user_meta($aid, 'si_office_status', 'true');     
    }
    echo "value is set!";
    die();
} 
die();   
}
```

Comment: Not so clear what do you mean by "but this Javascript below won't go back to the original page"

Comment: Agree with @Ramesh. Ajax is not suppose to redirect or go to another page - it was created for the exact opposite reason - to stay on the current page without a refresh, etc.

Comment: Ah, yes, I actually don't want it to leave the original page! :)  Maybe it's a wordpress thing... but I'm trying to have a link to click on to update metadata for a user without leaving the page...

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need to do a

```
 if(response.type == "success"){
```

block since this would have already been determined by the success callback being reached, if an error occurs it won't reach that block and go into your if statement like you want it to, instead you should have both a success callback and an error callback like so:

```
success: function(data) {
    // Your success here
},
error: function() {
    // Your error handler here
}
```

This may be why you're having troubles.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a speedy response... OK, so I tried updating my code as per below and retested with the same result, the page loads the "Value is set!" and stays on the success page URL: wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=outofoffice_ajax_request&outofoffice_value=true&aid=19&nonce=52477e05c4

Comment: AJAX requests won't load the page upon completion, only if you tell it to.

The idea behind AJAX is that you send back the new data and then include it in the page with your JS. You may have to just tell the page to reload using:
    document.location = document.location.href;

Comment: OK, buuuut I tried adding window.location.reload(true); in the success function and no change.... mmmm

Comment: Maybe I need to make the link load in the browser via Javascript rather than a traditional hard link to the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php... url?